# Several times locked Windows account – computer name?

Tags: windows, credentials, account

there are PCs in our domain,.. Every computer is connected to server, every user can access every computer using its user profile (windows user),.. In last months, one account is still being blocked (password is being wrongly entered three times) from some computer. Is there a way how can I find out, from which computer is the account blocked (from which computer there is always purposely entered bad credentials)?

Thanks for answer

Comment: I dont think this belongs here. Try superuser?

Answer (score 1):

as a starting Point for your troubleshooting, we don't know what troubleshooting you have already done, but, since it's a domain that all the clients are connected to, Logically there would have to be a Domain Account on the Server and the client, You could isolate the issue and Narrow down your options by finding out how many of the client machines, Have the Account, Named as the one that the server says, that failed to logon successfully,  then.. of the clients that have that account, Check the Event Logs and Event ID's and see what you can find there,   Here's a Link to help you out [[http://www.eventtracker.com/newsletters/following-a-users-logon-tracks-throughout-the-windows-domain/]](http://www.eventtracker.com/newsletters/following-a-users-logon-tracks-throughout-the-windows-domain/%5d)  Read it carefully and let me know how you go.